Construct a Binary tree from a python dictionary
The dictionary has key and value pairs of manager employee relationship, manager key can have multiple employees and those employees can have their own employees like below
data = {
    "Amy": ["Alice", "Charlie"],
    "Alice": ["Akon", "Eve"],
    "Eve": ["Frank", None],
    "Charlie": ["Bob", "Grace"]
}

while I can see all the nodes are getting added in the print statements below, but I am not able to print out the tree properly.
Here's the code
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def construct_binary_tree(data, root_key):
    if root_key not in data:
        return None
    
    print("Constructing node:", root_key)
    root = TreeNode(root_key)
    if root_key in data:
        children = data[root_key]
        left_child_key = children[0] if children and len(children) > 0 else None
        right_child_key = children[1] if children and len(children) > 1 else None
        print("Left child of", root_key, ":", left_child_key)
        print("Right child of", root_key, ":", right_child_key)
        if left_child_key:
            root.left = construct_binary_tree(data, left_child_key)
        if right_child_key:
            root.right = construct_binary_tree(data, right_child_key)
    
    return root

def print_tree(root, depth=0):
    if root:
        print("   " * depth + f"|-- {root.key}")
        print_tree(root.left, depth + 1)
        print_tree(root.right, depth + 1)

# Given data
data = {
    "Amy": ["Alice", "Charlie"],
    "Alice": ["Akon", "Eve"],
    "Eve": ["Frank", None],
    "Charlie": ["Bob", "Grace"]
}

# Construct binary tree
root_key = next(iter(data))
root = construct_binary_tree(data, root_key)

# Print binary tree in tree format
print_tree(root)

Here's the output I am seeing
Constructing node: Amy
Left child of Amy : Alice
Right child of Amy : Charlie
Constructing node: Alice
Left child of Alice : Akon
Right child of Alice : Eve
Constructing node: Eve
Left child of Eve : Frank
Right child of Eve : None
Constructing node: Charlie
Left child of Charlie : Bob
Right child of Charlie : Grace
|-- Amy
   |-- Alice
      |-- Eve
   |-- Charlie


You are testing whether a string is in the keys of data at the beginning of construct_binary_tree and returning None if it is not there. This means when you pass in a name like "Bob" it returns None immediately rather than a tree Node because it is not one of the keys of the dictionary. When you go to print it, there is no reference to "Bob", just None. Consider returning a tree node there instead of None.
def construct_binary_tree(data, root_key):
    if root_key not in data:
        return TreeNode(root_key)
    

Doing that will print:
|-- Amy
   |-- Alice
      |-- Akon
      |-- Eve
         |-- Frank
   |-- Charlie
      |-- Bob
      |-- Grace

There many be other issues because this method seems to depend on the data order to work, but it should help your immediate issue.

Thanks much, this helped with where I was stuck, I also updated the code now to construct non-binary tree in case we have more than 2 employees (child nodes)

This is a iterative approach:
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


def construct_binary_tree(data, root_key):
    if not root_key:
        return

    print("Constructing node:", root_key)
    root = TreeNode(root_key)
    if root_key in data:
        left_child_key, right_child_key = data[root_key]
        print("Left child of", root_key, ":", left_child_key)
        print("Right child of", root_key, ":", right_child_key)
        if left_child_key:
            root.left = construct_binary_tree(data, left_child_key)
        if right_child_key:
            root.right = construct_binary_tree(data, right_child_key)

    return root


def print_tree(root):
    q = [(root, 0)]  # Each item in the queue is now a tuple of (node, depth)
    res = []
    while q:
        node, depth = q.pop(0)
        res.append("|  " * depth + f"|-- {node.key}")
        if node.left is not None:
            q.append((node.left, depth + 1))  # Increase depth only when enqueuing a child node
            res.append("|  " * (depth + 1) + f"left child |-- {node.left.key}")
        else:
            res.append("|  " * (depth + 1) + f"left child |-- None")
        if node.right is not None:
            q.append((node.right, depth + 1))  # Increase depth only when enqueuing a child node
            res.append("|  " * (depth + 1) + f"right child |-- {node.right.key}")
        else:
            res.append("|  " * (depth + 1) + f"right child |-- None")
    return '\n'.join(res)


# Given data
data = {
    "Amy": ["Alice", "Charlie"],
    "Alice": ["Akon", "Eve"],
    "Eve": ["Frank", None],
    "Charlie": ["Bob", "Grace"]
}

# Construct binary tree
root_key = next(iter(data))
root = construct_binary_tree(data, root_key)

# Print binary tree in tree format
print(print_tree(root))


Prints:
Constructing node: Amy
Left child of Amy : Alice
Right child of Amy : Charlie
Constructing node: Alice
Left child of Alice : Akon
Right child of Alice : Eve
Constructing node: Akon
Constructing node: Eve
Left child of Eve : Frank
Right child of Eve : None
Constructing node: Frank
Constructing node: Charlie
Left child of Charlie : Bob
Right child of Charlie : Grace
Constructing node: Bob
Constructing node: Grace
|-- Amy
|  left child |-- Alice
|  right child |-- Charlie
|  |-- Alice
|  |  left child |-- Akon
|  |  right child |-- Eve
|  |-- Charlie
|  |  left child |-- Bob
|  |  right child |-- Grace
|  |  |-- Akon
|  |  |  left child |-- None
|  |  |  right child |-- None
|  |  |-- Eve
|  |  |  left child |-- Frank
|  |  |  right child |-- None
|  |  |-- Bob
|  |  |  left child |-- None
|  |  |  right child |-- None
|  |  |-- Grace
|  |  |  left child |-- None
|  |  |  right child |-- None
|  |  |  |-- Frank
|  |  |  |  left child |-- None
|  |  |  |  right child |-- None

Note
I also added the None children, which you can remove if you want.
There was just a minor bug in the construct binary tree that's fixed.
